# I can't send a Firebase Cloud Messaging push notification to my app i followed the steps but got nowhere

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I followed the steps and created an APN key and uploaded it, however it doesn't seem to recognize my app whenever i try to send a message through the cloud messaging part of firebase it says (0% of potential users are eligible for this campaign: 0). This is my entire app delegate file.My app can access the database and retrieve data just fine it's just the cloud messaging part.

```
      import UIKit
      import Firebase
      import CoreLocation
      import FirebaseMessaging
      import UserNotifications



      @UIApplicationMain
      class AppDelegate: UIResponder,UIApplicationDelegate, 
 UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{

var window: UIWindow?
let gcmMessageIDKey = "gsm.message_id"

let userNotificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FirebaseApp.configure()
   if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
              options: authOptions,
              completionHandler: {_, _ in })
          } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
          }

          Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
          application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


    return true


}



func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.


}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
  // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
  // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
  // TODO: Handle data of notification

  // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
  // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

  // Print message ID.
  if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
    print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
  }

  // Print full message.
  print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
  // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
  // TODO: Handle data of notification

  // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
  // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

  // Print message ID.
  if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
    print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
  }

  // Print full message.
  print(userInfo)

  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}


}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                          willPresent notification: UNNotification,
withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

// With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
// Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

// Print message ID.
if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
  print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
}

// Print full message.
print(userInfo)

// Change this to your preferred presentation option
completionHandler([.alert])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                          didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                          withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
// Print message ID.
if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
  print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
}

// Print full message.
print(userInfo)

completionHandler()
}
}




extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate{
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
  print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

  let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
  // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
  // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print(remoteMessage.appData)
}
}
```

Comment: Does it get fcm token?

Comment: yes it does print the token

Comment: Did you test your token with fcm console test notification?

Comment: yes i sent a test notification but it didn't receive it

Comment: please add this to your appdelegate and test it again:
  
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }

Comment: still no luck sir, the push notifications is enabled on both the xcode app and the apple developer website. but i haven't configured any push notifications certificates, would that be the problem?

Comment: yes, you should have certificate to use push notification

Comment: i created it and still nothing

Comment: I replied to you in chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I had the same problem(Xcode-11.3.1)
- I'm using the [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/8f2b0cd18d28b1b2152bda5333a570b8f3d074b0/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift#L40-L55) very long time. There was no problem. I could see the token in log. as usual.
- I used it again last day. I sent a notification and I saw it was successfully but I couldn't receive it with the device.
- I added Capability -> Push Notifications and Capability -> Background Modes -> Remote Notifications(check)
- I created APN key and all certificates but it didn't matter.
- Then I updated Xcode(11.4.1). It is working now. I wrote to explain that the problem is not code or certificate.

  ```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
      print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
  }
  ```

This function is important. If you can see this output, you can receive notification successfully:

> APNs token retrieved: 32 bytes